# How to get text on sidebar to show on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn HTML by creating a mess around the website, I have added a menu bar on the top right of my site but when I open up the display my text stops showing.

[the text showing up on the top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TO0t.png)

[The menu bar without text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLVAQ.png)

I want the text that shows up on the top from the first picture to show up on the menu bar.

This is my CSS

```
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        
    }
    
    nav{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 8vh;
        background-color: darkgray;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        
    }
    .logo{
        color: rgb(221, 220, 220);
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .nav-links{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .nav-links li{
        list-style: none;
    }
    .nav-links a{
        color: rgb(221, 220, 220);
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    .burger{
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .burger div{
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: rgb(221, 220, 220);
        margin: 5px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:1024px){
        .nav-links{
            width: 30%;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width:768px){
        body{
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .nav-links{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            height: 92vh;
            top: 8vh;
            background-color: darkgray;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            width: 20%;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        .nav-links li {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .burger{
            display: block;
        }
    }
    
    .nav-active{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    
    @keyframes navLinkFade{
        from{
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(30px);
        }
        to{
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }
    }
    .toggle .line1{
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
    }
    .toggle .line2{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .toggle .line3{
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
    }
```

This is my HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d82fb47a55.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <title>FutAvion</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <h4><u>FutAvion</u></h4>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <script src="apps"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is my js

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    menu.addEventListener('click',()=> {
        //toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        //Anumate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => { 
            if(link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else {
                link.style.animation = 'navLinkFade 0.5s ease fowards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s';
            }
        });
        //menu Animation
        menu.classList.toggle('toggle');

    });

}

navSlide();
```

Comment: Please, add your html.

Comment: can you post your js file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your problem you gave `.nav-links li`  an `opacity` of  `0`
Therefore the `li` links won't show. So to fix that you just need to remove the `opacity` and you are set to go.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
    .nav-links li {
        /* opacity: 0; */
    }
```

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
console.log('am working');
const navSlide = () => {
  const menu = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

  menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

    //   Anumate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = 'navLinkFade 0.5s ease fowards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s';
      }
    });
    //menu Animation
    menu.classList.toggle('toggle');

  });

};

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: darkgray;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(221, 220, 220);
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 30%;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(221, 220, 220);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 220, 220);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: darkgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 20%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h4><u>FutAvion</u></h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you so much!